# Как удалить из строки все кроме цифр?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как удалить из строки все символы кроме цифры?

Comment: все кроме цифр - `^[^0-9]$`

Comment: @cmd, не правда. И вообще, как оно к вопросу относится?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заменить все `\D` на пустую сторку.

Comment: А модификатор `g` зачем нужен в replace?

Comment: @Visman, а не нужен? В js нужен.

Comment: @Visman, Спасибо большое. Ваш вариант работает

Comment: @Qwertiy, http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @Visman, ошибся =). Благодарность адресована @Qwertiy. И кстати, с модификатором `g` в php не срабатывает регулярка.

Comment: @KernelPanic, его в php просто нет. Ссылку для Qwertiy дал выше на существующие модификаторы.

Comment: @Visman, ok, убрал.

Answer (score 10):

```
$value = 'jfFfhf55555kdjd89';
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё достаточно просто и по-моему это можно было найти даже в гугле

```
<?php
preg_replace('~\D+~','', $string);
?>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нормальный ответ же.